# Ionic slide box How to play a sound when switching slide? without a click

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i want to play a sound when switching slides from ionic slide box, i need it without clicking buttons, i have already tried to put a ng-focus directive from angular and i tried the property on-slide-changed from ionic slide box... here is my code:

```js
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" class="fondo-rojo" show-pager="false" does-continue="true" ng-if="sencillo.length">
                <ion-slide ng-repeat="senci in sencillo" ng-init="play('/android_asset/www/raw/'+senci.sound_title+'.mp3')" repeat-done="repeatDone()">
                      
                           <h1 class="margen-slide slide-estilo">{{senci.title}}</h1>
                           <a align="center" style="text-align:center !important;" ng-click="play('/android_asset/www/raw/'+senci.sound_title+'.mp3')"><img style="text-align:center !important;"  ng-src="img/sonidos/play.png" width="70px" height="70px"></a>
                           <!--<button ng-click="nextSlide()"> >> </button>-->
                       
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
```

Controller

```js
.controller("mediaCtrl", function($scope,$ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia, $ionicLoading) {
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
    $scope.play = function(src) {
        var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(src);
        //var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
        media.play();
        //$cordovaMedia.play(media);
    }
 
    var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    }
    $scope.slideHasChanged = function(src,$index){
        
        console.info("El Slide Cambio y es el: " + $index);
        //alert('slideHasChanged $index=' + $index);
       if($index >= 0){
            $scope.play(src);
       }
     };
 })
    
})
```

I hope you can help me thanks for read, regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you only need to reference "/raw", you don't need "android_asset/...", Also I am not sure what does your "play" function look like.

But try this

```
//play it on slide change
$scope.slideHasChanged = function($index){

   //init your audio depending on the selected slide
   clickAudio = new Audio('raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3');

   clickAuido.play();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, for android i need "android_asset/", for IOS i just use "/raw". I tried something like the code above but if the `on-slide-changed` property can be used only in `ion-slide-box` directive how could use the scope `senci.sound_title` which should be under `ng-repeat`?, I could use  `on-slide-changed`  `in ion-slide` directive?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but I presume you want to play different audio per each slide. I updated the code have a look.

Comment: wow thank you very much , that was just what I needed , so I adapted it to my code and it worked perfectly , the only problem is that my first slide does not play sound automatically , I guess this is because it does just by changing the slide, any suggestions for solve this bro?

Comment: Are you always loading slide "0" first?

Comment: Yes  it does, the problem is that for the first slide, the sound does not play automatically, i tried the ng-init directive like this `ng-init="play('/android_asset/www/raw/'+sencillo[$index].sound_title+'.mp3')"` in `<ion-slide-box>` but this play the first sound as many times as row have the scope, so it does not work for me.